# use of undeclared identifier 'myWebMain'?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm working on a cordova app and im trying to get html5 on ios to autoplay since it was disable by apple, i'm using the following codes.

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    NSURLRequest* request = [webView request];
    NSString *page = [request.URL lastPathComponent];
    if ([page isEqualToString:@"index.html"]){
        NSString *js = @"startVideo();";
        [myWebMain stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

but when i run the app i get this error message

> use of undeclared identifier 'myWebMain'

[image]

I have no knowledge on xcode, and i was wondering how can i fix my problem?

Comment: Have you declared variable `myWebMain`? Like `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *myWebMain;` or `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebMain;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change `myWebMain` to `webView`

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

Comment: This answer is the closest answer i got so fall but i still that creates one error i can't fix. [IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/15q3h3k.png[/IMG]

Comment: it's hard to tell without seeing your full code, but I bet you are missing a closing }

Comment: I just put together the whole code on an image i don't know if that can help you reading the whole code. http://oi60.tinypic.com/bdoztz.jpg

Comment: And nope it was not a closing bracket

Comment: no, I can't read it on that image. Why don't you paste the code into pastebin or something like that?

Comment: I've just tested and yes, you are missing the closing } just before the - (void)webView:(UIWebView*)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error

Answer (score 0):

U need to make an outlet of `UIWebView` with the name `myWebMain` like

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIWebView *myWebMain
```

in your .h file.